# Image carousel webpart

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I am working with a client who wants a carousel displaying in SharePoint.  As you can probably guess they want the carousel to slide in or fade in an image and then go to a link when the user clicks.  Obviously the link is dynamic to the page that the currently displayed image relates to.

Sorry if I have dumbed down the forum telling you something obvious.

What I would like to know is does anyone have a position experience of implementing this in SharePoint 2013?

I'm happy to go with a custom or a commercial web part but really looking for a pain free solution.

The user of the site will be authenticated when the web part displays and I will be producing custom master pages and page layouts if this is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

their is 3rd party solution for this.You can try their license for 30 days.

[Image Carousel Web Part](http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5796)

Their is also a free solution at codeplex.

[Sharepoint Carousel](http://spcarousel.codeplex.com/)

Also have a look on this:
http://www.ashokraja.me/post/SharePoint-2013-Carousel-WebPart-with-Nivo-Slider.aspx